# Variation on Bubble Sort infinite loop error

Tags: python, while-loop, bubble-sort

In a particular board game, there is exactly one row and it comprises N spaces, numbered 0 through N - 1 from left to right. There are also N marbles, numbered 0 through N - 1, initially placed in some arbitrary order. After that, there are two moves available that only can be done one at a time:

- Switch: Switch the marbles in positions 0 and 1.
- Rotate: Move the
  marble in position 0 to position N - 1, and move all other marbles
  one space to the left (one index lower).

The objective is to arrange the marbles in order, with each marble i in position i.

The code I wrote works for the example posted on the problem (1 3 0 2), but when I add the extra number 4 randomly to the list the while loop never terminates. Looking at the sorted sequence, it seems to loop through a number of the same sequence repeatedly. I am not sure why it would work for one series but not the next one.

Bonus, I can't seem to figure out how to print the output as numbers separated by a space vs. as a list with brackets and commas. The problem asks that we print the output as numbers separated by spaces. Any help on that would be appreciated.

```
class MarblesBoard:
    """creates a marble board with number marbles in specific spots"""
    def __init__(self, marble_sequence):
        self.board = [x for x in marble_sequence]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.board)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%r " % (self.board)

    def switch(self):
        """switch the marbles in position 0 and 1"""
        self.board[0], self.board[1] = self.board[1], self.board[0]
        return self.board

    def rotate(self):
        """Move the marble in position 0 to position N - 1, and move all other marbles one space to the left (one index lower)"""
        copy_board = self.board.copy()
        copy_board[len(self.board)-1] = self.board[0]
        for x in range(1, len(self.board)):
            copy_board[x - 1] = self.board[x]
        self.board = copy_board
        return self.board

    def is_sorted(self):
        return self.board == sorted(self.board):

class Solver:
    """solves the marble sorting game when given a marble board as input"""

    def __init__(self, MarblesBoard):
        self.steps = 0
        self.board = MarblesBoard.board
        return

    def solve(self):
        n = len(self.board)
        # print("n = ", n)
        print(self.board)
        while MarblesBoard.is_sorted(self) == False:
            if self.board[0] > self.board[1]:
                MarblesBoard.rotate(self)
                print(self.board)
                self.steps += 1
            else:
                MarblesBoard.switch(self)
                print(self.board)
                self.steps += 1
        print("total steps: ", self.steps)
```

With regards to output, the code works fine for the example output here:

```
board2 = MarblesBoard((1,3,0,2))
solver = Solver(board2)
solver.solve()

[1, 3, 0, 2]
[3, 1, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 3, 1]
[2, 0, 3, 1]
[0, 3, 1, 2]
[3, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
total steps:  7
```

However, if I add a 4 into the starting board:

```
board2 = MarblesBoard((1,3,0,2,4))
solver = Solver(board2)
solver.solve()

[1, 3, 0, 2, 4]
[3, 1, 0, 2, 4]
[1, 0, 2, 4, 3]
[0, 2, 4, 3, 1]
[2, 0, 4, 3, 1]
[0, 4, 3, 1, 2]
[4, 0, 3, 1, 2]
[0, 3, 1, 2, 4]
[3, 0, 1, 2, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 3]
[1, 0, 2, 4, 3]
[0, 2, 4, 3, 1]
[2, 0, 4, 3, 1]
[0, 4, 3, 1, 2]
[4, 0, 3, 1, 2]
[0, 3, 1, 2, 4]
[3, 0, 1, 2, 4]
```

Note that 3 0 1 2 4 repeats as the second iteration and the last listed iteration. Due to the structure of the while loop, since the same sequence occurs, the same steps get implemented and the loop continues infinitely.

Comment: Your `is_sorted` method can simply be `return self.board == sorted(self.board)`. Glad you didn't return `False` when the condition is `True`.

Comment: [Similar previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840758/sorting-numbers-with-mix-of-switch-and-rotate-in-python)

Comment: @dumdum--only if it completely answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, how is it a variation on Bubble Sort exactly? Most sorts have a way of keeping the sorted and unsorted data in separate areas, so that it's clear what has already been sorted. This sort doesn't seem to do that.

It looks the like the only criteria for a switch to occur is when `board[0] > board[1]`. Is that really all there is?

My suggestions for the code are below:

```
class MarblesBoard:

    def __init__(self, marble_sequence):
        self.board = [x for x in marble_sequence]
```

Isn't that a bit redundant? Why not:

```
class MarblesBoard:

    def __init__(self, marble_sequence):
        self.board = marble_sequence
```

> I can't seem to figure out how to print the output as numbers
>   separated by a space

That takes me to your implementation of `__str__`:

```
def __str__(self):
        return str(self.board)
```

That won't do. Take a look at the string I get back when I try to do something similar in the shell:

```
>>> str([1, 2, 3])
'[1, 2, 3]'
>>>
```

You're better off using `str.join`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return " ".join(map(str, self.board))
```

Your `switch` method looks fine, except for the fact that you don't need to return anything from it. Just swap the elements and that's all you need to do.

If I've understood the `rotate` method correctly, it can be simplified:

```
def rotate(self):
    self.board.append(self.board.pop(0))
```

Again, you don't need to return anything from this function.

Your `is_sorted` can be simplified as well:

```
def is_sorted(self):
    return self.board == sorted(self.board)
```

I would also maybe add a method called `should_rotate` to your `MarblesBoard` class, which returns `True` or `False` depending on whether or not the solver should rotate or switch. It's meant to be used by the solver later:

```
def should_rotate(self):
    return self.board[0] > self.board[1]
```

Next, the `Solver` class. First the `__init__` method:

By naming the parameter `MarblesBoard`, (the same name as the class), you are shadowing the identifier of the class - so I wouldn't call the parameter that. I think `marbles_board` is a better name.

Second, I don't see a good reason for explicitly making `steps` an instance variable in your `__init__`, since the only place you're using it is in the `solve` method. I would just get rid of it for now.

Third, I don't think it's a good idea to bind `self.board` to the `board` object of the `MarblesBoard` instance. If your `Solver` class basically just wraps around a `MarblesBoard.board`, you might as well not even make this class and just do all your solving in the `MarblesBoard` class. Again, you don't need to explicitly `return` from your `__init__`.

```
class Solver:

    def __init__(self, marbles_board):
        self.marbles_board = marbles_board
```

The `solve` can be simplified a bit as well:

```
def solve(self):

    number_of_steps = 0

    while not self.marbles_board.is_sorted():
        if self.marbles_board.should_rotate():
            self.marbles_board.rotate()
        else:
            self.marbles_board.switch()
        number_of_steps += 1
    print(f"Number of steps: {number_of_steps}")
```

It's kind of funny that your implementation of `solve` worked as well as it did, seeing as how you are passing in `self` (the `Solver` object) as an argument for the `rotate` and `switch` methods.

Comment: My understanding is that traditional bubble sort looks at index [0] and [1] and sorts that before moving to index [1] and [2] and sorts that...all the way until index [n-1] and [n]. Then it repeats this up to index [n-2] and [n-1] and so on. This version switches only index [0] and [1] but can shift down the list using the rotate function. I would liken it to a changed reference frame. Instead of moving the index down the line, you move the list.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! There is still an infinite while loop when add a 4, but this code is so much easier to read now.