# Python: Sorting Marbles with switch and rotate - Need help in optimizing a working solution

Tags: python

I have made a couple modifications to the switch/rotate routine for the classic Marbles game. The modifications are

1. Using a random_select method that can help pick either switch or rotate
2. Create a method called first_two that rotates l[0] and l[1] and avoids the switch as that would be counter productive

With these two changes, I was able to significantly cut down the number of steps (by a factor of 5+)

I am trying one final enhancement; ie using a control_list to avoid duplicates. This is to skip combinations that already exist. And this is where I need help.

Code for both Classes is below. I have tried a variation of [sorting numbers with mix of switch and rotate in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840758/sorting-numbers-with-mix-of-switch-and-rotate-in-python)

```
import random

class MarblesBoard:
    """creates a marble board with number marbles in specific spots"""
    def __init__(self, marble_sequence):
        self.board = [x for x in marble_sequence]

    def __str__(self):
        return " ".join(map(str, self.board))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%r " % (self.board)

    def switch(self):
        """switch the marbles in position 0 and 1"""
        self.board[0], self.board[1] = self.board[1], self.board[0]
        return self.board

    def rotate(self):
         """
         Rotates item in position o to position N-1. All remaning items are moved as a result (1 step to the left)
         """
        self.board = self.board[1:] + [self.board[0]]
        return self.board
    
    def is_solved(self):
        return self.board == sorted(self.board)
    
    def random_select(self):
        # used a random generator for True/False -- used to select Switch or Rotate
        return random.choice([True, False])

    def first_two(self):
        return self.board[0] < self.board[1]
```

```
class Solver:
    """solves the marble sorting game when given a marble board as input"""

    def __init__(self, marbles_board):
        self.marbles_board = marbles_board
        
    def solve(self):
        steps = 0
        myboard = self.marbles_board
        control_list = []
        control_list.append(str(myboard))
        print(control_list)

        while not self.marbles_board.is_solved():
            if self.marbles_board.first_two():
                self.marbles_board.rotate()
                if str(self.marbles_board) in control_list: pass
                else:control_list.append((str(self.marbles_board)))
                if self.marbles_board.is_solved(): break

            else:
                self.marbles_board.switch()
                if str(self.marbles_board) in control_list: pass
                else:control_list.append((str(self.marbles_board)))
                if self.marbles_board.is_solved(): break


            if self.marbles_board.random_select():
                self.marbles_board.rotate()
                if str(self.marbles_board) in control_list: pass#self.marbles_board.switch()
                else:control_list.append((str(self.marbles_board)))

                if self.marbles_board.is_solved(): break
            
            steps += 1
        print(control_list)
        print(f"Number of steps: {steps}")
```

Comment: Optimizing working code is better suited for Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you @ blackbrandt. I am relatively new this and learning the ropes